# Fill in the commutative diagram of exact sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, exact-sequence, projective-module

I don’t know how to create an exact sequence in the second coulumn...

Can $P_{i}⊕Q_{i}$ be the answer to the red boxes? ($i=1,2,3$)

[image]

Comment: This is called "Horseshoe lemma", see Lemma 2.2.8 in Weibel, *Homological Algebra*.

Answer (score 1):

$\require{AMScd}$
Since $Q_0$ is projective and $g$ is epic, there exists a morphism $t:Q_0\to B$ such that $tg=g\circ t=\varrho_0$.
Then we have a commutative diagram with exact rows:
\begin{CD}
\{0\}@>>>P_0@>[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\end{smallmatrix}]>>P_0\times Q_0@>\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right]>>Q_0@>>>\{0\}\\
@.@V\delta_0VV@VV\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\delta_0f\\t\end{smallmatrix}\right]V@VV\varrho_0V\\
\{0\}@>>>A@>>f>B@>>g>C@>>>\{0\}
\end{CD}